# Wait for asynchronous block to finish - signal (seems) do not work

Tags: xcode, macos, callback, objective-c-blocks, semaphore

I am using cryptotokenkit to send/receive data from smart card. The use case is, I must have the response from the card API before I do something else.

In my case I found that this line is always called after kMaxBlockingTimeSmartCardResponse (= 10) seconds. 
From

```
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
```

it directly goes to

```
dispatch_time_t timeout = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(kMaxBlockingTimeSmartCardResponse * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, timeout);
```

Then wait for 10 seconds to come to the block call. Its not the block callback delaying. If I set the dispatch time 20 or 30 seconds, it wait for 20 or 30 seconds to execute. The wait call really wait for the specified time then callback block is executed.

What I am doing wrong? I wonder if this is related to adObserver.

```
- (void) updateSlots {
    self.slotNames = [self.manager slotNames];
    self.slotModels = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.slots = [NSMutableArray new];

    if([self.slotNames count] > 0)
    {
        for (NSString *slotName in self.slotNames)
        {
            NSLog(@"SmartCard reader found: %@", slotName);
            // semaphore BLOCK starts
            dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
            [self.manager getSlotWithName:slotName reply:^(TKSmartCardSlot *slot)
             {
                 if (slot) {
                     SCSlotModel *slotModel = [SCSlotModel new];
                     [self.slotModels addObject:slotModel];

                     [self.slots addObject:slot];
                     [slot addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"state"
                               options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial
                               context:nil];

                     slotModel.suffixedName = slotName; // NOT slot.name; original name is suffixed with 01, 02 etc.
                     slotModel.slot = slot;
                     slotModel.cardStatus = [CardUtil mapCardStatus:slot.state];
                     DLog(@"slot: %@, slotmodel: %@",slot.name, slotModel);
                 } else {
                     NSLog(@"Did not find slot with name: %@", slotName);
                 }
                 dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
             }];
            dispatch_time_t timeout = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(kMaxBlockingTimeSmartCardResponse * NSEC_PER_SEC));
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, timeout);
            // semaphore BLOCK ends
            self.errorCode = SCPNoError;
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"No slot available.");
        self.errorCode = SCPErrorReaderNotFound;
    }
}
```

`getSlotWithName` is the method from `TKSmartCardSlotManager`

```
/// Instantiates smartcard reader slot of specified name.  If specified name is not registered, returns nil.
- (void)getSlotWithName:(NSString *)name reply:(void(^)(TKSmartCardSlot *__nullable slot))reply;
```

But in other places it works as expected, for the same type of asynchronous calls.

```
- (BOOL) beginSession:(TKSmartCard *)card
{
    __block BOOL response = NO;
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [card beginSessionWithReply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        response = success;
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"Could not begin session.");
        }
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Could not begin session with error %@", error);
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    }];

    dispatch_time_t timeout = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(kMaxBlockingTimeSmartCardResponse * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, timeout);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: You would benefit from applying an asynchronous programming style. Since your `updateSlots` method uses an asynchronous method, this method becomes asynchronous as well: add a parameter for a completion block to `updateSlots` and call this block in the completion handler `reply`  in  `getSlotWithName`. Then call `updateSlots` with a continuation, that is - a completion block - and do what ever you want to do in order to continue.

Comment: thanks. I shall try that. but in other places it work as expected. updated my code with that part.

Answer (score 0):

What thread does `getSlotWithName:reply:` call its reply handler back on?
If for example `updateSlots` is executed on the main thread and you are doing something like this:

```
... // some async operation in `getSlotWithName:reply:` has completed
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    reply(slot)
});
```

then you would have ended up queueing your reply on the main thread however the main thread is currently locked with your semaphore.

Ensuring you call `dispatch_semaphore_signal()` from a thread other than the one you have locked should fix your issue.

---

**Side Note:** GCD and semaphores do the trick here but there are better ways you could perform actions after an async operation completes rather than letting a thread get locked up.. For example, delegate callbacks.
Not got enough information here to suggest anything exact but there are other options out there :)